# Mailx from within a C program?

Tags: c, shell, concatenation, mailx

I'm hoping to send a message via mailx to a list of recipients from within my C code.

I want to send an email containing the contents of the 'message' variable to everyone in the file /home/me/Email_List.txt.

```
if(send_email)
{
  char* message = "Testing email";
  //send contents of  'message' to everyone in /home/me/Email_List.txt
}
```

I need help with both the C program and the mailx command. Here's my mailx command that doesn't quite work:

```
//This works, but I don't want to send the contents of Email_List.txt
cat /home/me/Email_List.txt /home/me/Email_List.txt | mailx -t -s "Test"

//This doesn't work, error:
//cat: cannot open Test Text
cat /home/me/Email_List.txt "Test Text" | mailx -t -s "Test"
```

I could write my text to a file before sending it, but that seems inefficient.

Thoughts?

Comment: this has nothing to do with mailx. `cat` expects a list of filenames to open and spit out their contents of. `cat "Test Text"` is going to LITERALLY look for a file named `Test Text` and try to open it - and fail.

Comment: In your second command use echo "Test Text" rather than cat. It is trying to open a file with that name

Comment: Changing cat to echo gets me "No recepients specified"

Comment: @user3704313 That's right. You haven't specified receivers. `echo "hi" | mailx -t -s "Test" user@example.com` is proper use. Using this you should (hopefully) able to write a loop and do what you want.

Comment: you have to mention the recipient alongwith your mailx command.I think it goes like this mailx -s "Test"  user_name

Comment: The recipients are in /home/me/Email_List.txt.

Comment: Because of the `-t` option to `mailx`, your `Email_List.txt` file must contain a line such as `To: user1 user2@example.com` and such like; you can have `Cc:` and `Bcc:` lines too.  End that file with a blank line.  If you need to continue a line, break it at a white space character and put the continuation on another line indented (2-4 spaces should work, I think). The list might need to be comma-separated instead of blank-separated (and then you split at a comma).

Comment: The contents of /home/me/Email_List.txt is
"to:My.email@company.com"

Comment: The file needs to start with `To: My.email@company.com`; it is case-sensitive and space sensitive; there must be a space after the colon.  The email address itself is not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working at the command line, I got this to work for me (with my normal corporate email address in place of `me@example.com`, of course):

```
mailx -s "Just a test" -t <<EOF
To: me@example.com
Subject: Just a test with a subject

Just testing mailx -t which seems to ignore -s options too
-=JL=-
EOF
```

The `-s` option subject line was ignored, as hinted in the body text.  (This is a `mailx` version `12.5 6/20/10` on a machine running a derivative of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.)

Note that the `To:` line is case-sensitive and space-sensitive (at least there must be a space after the colon).  This is standard notation for the headers defined by RFC-822 (or whatever its current incarnation is).  When I tried with the `-s` option but no `Subject:` line, I got a message without a subject in my inbox.

The following should work for you:

```
$ cat /home/me/Email_list.txt
To: My.email@company.com
Subject: Test email

$ { cat /home/me/Email_List.txt; echo "Test Text"; } | mailx -t
$
```

Note that blank line!  Or you could use a plain `echo;` before the `echo "Test text";`.  The semicolons are needed in the `{ ... }` notation.

Comment: That works! Now I need to invoke that line in my C program. I can just use system() for that, right?

Comment: Yes; you should be able to use `system()` with that command line as the string argument (a literal string, or a string built from pieces at runtime.